# Activate windows under mouse through mouse hook

Tags: c++, winapi, autoit

Basically i make mousestruct in the hook

```
MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* str;
```

Then make it from lparam,

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
str = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
    ...
```

Then I catch mousemovements

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    wParm = AU3_WM_MOUSEMOVE;
    fromp = WindowFromPoint(str->pt);
```

Then validate and try not to send to many messages...

```
if (fromp != currentwindow) 
{
    currentwindow= fromp;
    PostMessage(m_hHwndMouse, wParm,(WPARAM)( (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam )->hwnd, LPARAM(fromp));
}
break;
```

This sends the mousemove message along with hwnd to my autoit app which inspects hwnd and if that hwnd is not active it activates it.

```
Func mouse_func($hWndGUI, $MsgID, $wParam, $lParam)

Select


    Case $MsgID = $WM_AUTOITMOUSEMOVE

        If GUICtrlRead($activateundermouse) = 1 And $sitting = 0 Then
            ;Local $starttime = _Timer_Init()
            If StringInStr(WinGetTitle($lParam), "ID=") Then
                If Not WinActive($lParam) Then
                    ;ConsoleWrite("HOVERING NEW, Activate It: " & WinGetTitle($lParam) & @LF)
                    WinActivate($lParam)
                EndIf
                ;ConsoleWrite("diff is > " & _Timer_Diff($starttime) & @LF)
            EndIf
        EndIf
```

This is how I am activating window that is hovered by the mouse but the problem is that rarely autoit wont read the message that should signal new window being hovered(or the dll with hook didnt send it, I dont know)

Also if the window is overlapping another window and both of them are valid windows that should be activate once hovered I get flickering as autoit is constantly trying to activate the current window and the overlapped one, in a loop

Is there something that perhaps I missed or could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the blocking `SendMessage` instead depending on surrounding implementation. `PostMessage` will send to the window message queue but may not have the priority you expect as it returns without waiting for the processing of the message.

Also check out `SetCapture` and `ReleaseCapture` to change which window is capturing mouse events based on a hit test in mouse move as an alternative to forwarding. Only one window at a time can capture mouse events using these functions so that will solve your flicker issue of the windows forwarding messages to each other most likely.

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest just to use the facility built into Windows. For example on Windows 7 it looks like this:

[image]

This capability is present in older versions of Windows too but is not exposed in such a simple interface. Instead you have to set it with a PowerToy or through [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx).

As [Raymond Chen explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/02/10170483.aspx), this is a user preference which should not be changed without the user's consent.

Comment: Of course, this is just option from my gui that users decide to use themselves :)

Comment: I'm curious. Is there a reason why you wish to implement this feature yourself rather than relying on the system? I'd guess the system's implementation would implement it better.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and advocates changing the user's system globally to gain application functionality. I'm curious would you also prefer changing the system font for all applications over writing code in an application to use a specific font?

Comment: @AJG85 It seems to me that OP is attempting to implement system-wide functionality. Am I reading the question incorrectly? How can you tell that OP wants to apply it selectively for some but not all top level windows?

Comment: @David: It's true I was assuming this is for MDI style application or suite of applications OP is developing otherwise coding wouldn't make much sense and you'd be right.

Comment: @AJG85 OP appears to be using a mouse hook which reeks of system-wide DLL injection to me. If it was all for applications under OP's control then there would be no hooks and no Autoit. But I could be wrong—it's happened before many times!!

Comment: @David: I've seen stranger things but your guess is probably closer to the mark than mine after all.